# Java convert from Iterator<Integer> to PrimitiveIterator.OfInt

Tags: java

Like in the title - i've got an `Iterator<Integer>` and want to convert it to a `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where are you stuck at exactly? Just implement `nextInt` and `hasNext` by delegating to your `Iterator<Integer>`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a simple wrapper for the Iterator.

The method creating it could look as follows:

```java
    private PrimitiveIterator.OfInt toPrimitiveIterator(Iterator<Integer> iterator){
        return new PrimitiveIterator.OfInt() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }
            
            @Override
            public int nextInt() {
                return iterator.next();
            }
        };
    }
```